# Swift XCode getting internal errors when using enums

Tags: xcode, swift, enums

When using dot notation for enums using Swift, I always get internal errors (XCode kind of crashes)

For example

```
enum WeatherData {
    case current, forecast, forecastTenDay, yesterday
}

let dataType: WeatherData = .current
```

As soon as I type in the period, it all goes weird.
No syntax coloring temporarily, and although it recovers, it's really annoying.

I use MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012).

Anyone else getting this error?

Comment: You mean Xcode has bugs? I never would have thought....

Comment: Invariably crashes unless the enum is declared in the same file. So annoying

Comment: Works fine on Xcode 7.0, what version are you using?